# Python WebSocketApp info

Tags: python, python-3.x, websocket

I'm trying to wrap my head around the usage of websocket. Here's my code:

```
import websocket

def on_message(ws, message):
    print(message)
def on_error(ws, error):
    print(error)
def on_close(ws):
    print('Websocket: closed')
def on_open(ws):
    print('Websocket: open')

ws = websocket.WebSocketApp('ws://echo.websocket.org/',
                          on_message = on_message,
                          on_error = on_error,
                          on_close = on_close,
                          on_open = on_open)

ws.run_forever()
```

First, why would I put

```
ws.on_open = on_open
```

instead of passing it while defining ws? (As I did in the code)

Moreoever, how can I send a message? I could include 
`ws.send(json.dumps("Hello"))` under

`def on_open(ws)`, is there some other way?

Finally, I'm not able to close the connection given that `ws.run_forever()` never stops, how can I do it? I tried to include `ws.close()` under `def on_open(ws)` but then I don't receive any message.

What I'm trying to get is how I can transpose this:

```
ws = ws.create_connection('ws://echo.websocket.org/')
ws.send(json.dumps("Hello"))
result = json.loads(ws.recv())
print(result)
```

using WebSocketApp, that is having the messages pushed printed directly, without having to request the result.